# Java runtime exec zip command with "*" character

Tags: java, linux

I want to zip contents of folder without including folder it self using Java Runtime

For example: zip folder /home/duyvt/example

In terminal, I exec the following commands and it works well. Archive.zip will include only contents of example folder.

> $ cd /home/duyvt/example.
>
> $ zip -r /home/duyvt/archive.zip *

But in Java Runtime, it does not work.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("zip -r /home/duyvt/archive.zip *", null, new File("/home/duyvt/example"));
```

It seems Java Runtime does not understand "*" character.

I have also tried to use "ProcessBuilder" but not work too.

Is there anyone can help me ?.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, it is the *shell* that understands and expands `*`.
On Windows, the command program has to do it itself.

Java is generic, and does not implement shell functionality.

If you want shell functionality, run the command through the shell, e.g.

```
sh -c 'zip -r /home/duyvt/archive.zip *'
```

**UPDATE**

From javadoc of [`exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29):

> This is a convenience method. An invocation of the form `exec(command, envp, dir)` behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation `exec(cmdarray, envp, dir)`, where `cmdarray` is an array of all the tokens in `command`.
>
> More precisely, the `command` string is broken into tokens using a `StringTokenizer` created by the call `new StringTokenizer(command)` with no further modification of the character categories. The tokens produced by the tokenizer are then placed in the new string array `cmdarray`, in the same order.

Since `StringTokenizer` doesn't understand the shell quoting using `''`, the command is split incorrectly, and you'll have to do it yourself:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "sh",
                                         "-c",
                                         "zip -r /home/duyvt/archive.zip *" },
                          null, new File("/home/duyvt/example"));
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it not work. Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh -c 'zip -r /home/duyvt/archive.zip *'", null, new File("/home/duyvt/example"));

Answer (score 0):

Start shell and pass it a command, like so:

```
"sh -c 'zip -r /home/duyvt/archive.zip *'"
```